# Incorrect mouseover event triggered on Chome on Linux?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I'm detecting mouseenter events:

```
// triggered when mousing over the green div
$('#dock').mouseenter(function() {
    alert('moused over!');
});
```

However, if I have a select tag after my div, this is triggering the mouseover event when it's opened:

```
    <div id="dock">
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        <select name="product_tier" id="id_product_tier">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="1">test-product-tier</option>
        </select>

    </div>
```

I've tested this on Chrome and Chromium 27.0.1453.93 (Windows: OK, OS X: OK, Linux: Fails as described), IE 9 (Windows: OK), Opera (Linux: OK), Firefox 21 (Linux: OK).

I can't reproduce it on jsFiddle or jsBin, but here's a gist you can run: https://gist.github.com/Wilfred/5679748 .

Any ideas what's wrong? Is this a Chrome bug?

Comment: Try adding some content inside the div and see if it still happens.

Comment: @tymeJV adding some text inside `#dock` or `#container` does not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new jQuery way supported in jQuery 1.7+

```
$("#dock").on("click touchstart", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yfHZE/

Disclaimer: I didn't try this in Linux, but it should work.

Comment: This code triggers clicking the div, I want mouseover. However, if I change your code to `$("#dock").on("mouseover",` I get the same buggy behaviour.